# TypeScript - specific string types

Tags: types, typescript

I'm looking for a better way to distinguish between different types of strings in my program- for example, absolute paths and relative paths. I want to be able to have functions take or return a certain type with a compiler error if I mess it up.

For example,

```
function makeAbsolute(path: RelativePath): AbsolutePath {
}
```

where AbsolutePath and RelativePath and really just strings. I experimented with type aliases, but those don't actually create a new type. Also interfaces -

```
interface AbsolutePath extends String { }
interface RelativePath extends String { }
```

but since those interfaces are compatible, the compiler doesn't prevent me from mixing them up. I don't see how I can do this without either adding a property to the interface to make them not compatible (and either actually adding that property to the string, or casting around it), or using a wrapper class. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. You want different types depending on what the string contains? If so, you might want to check out `document.createElement` in lib.d.ts, which I believe determines a function overload using what the string value contains. For example, it will return a `HTMLDivElement` when you supply `"DIV"` as argument.

Comment: No, not depending on the content of the string. Just two types which are actually any string, but the compiler treats them as incompatible.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if one can fool the structural type system in TS to achieve this somehow.

Comment: @Alex [There.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37054964/2788872)

Comment: @JohnWhite Whoops, my browser did not show me that :)

Comment: The short of it is that there is currently no clean way of doing this in TypeScript  (as of v3.3). Some potential workarounds follow, but all have drawbacks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
abstract class RelativePath extends String {
    public static createFromString(url: string): RelativePath {
        // validate if 'url' is indeed a relative path
        // for example, if it does not begin with '/'
        // ...
        return url as any;
    }

    private __relativePathFlag;
}

abstract class AbsolutePath extends String {
    public static createFromString(url: string): AbsolutePath {
        // validate if 'url' is indeed an absolute path
        // for example, if it begins with '/'
        // ...
        return url as any;
    }

    private __absolutePathFlag;
}
```

```auto
var path1 = RelativePath.createFromString("relative/path");
var path2 = AbsolutePath.createFromString("/absolute/path");

// Compile error: type 'AbsolutePath' is not assignable to type 'RelativePath'
path1 = path2;

console.log(typeof path1); // "string"
console.log(typeof path2); // "string"
console.log(path1.toUpperCase()); // "RELATIVE/PATH"
```

This is just so wrong on every levels you could write a book about it... -- but it *does* work nicely, and it *does* get the job done.

Since their creation is controlled as such, `AbsolutePath` and `RelativePath` instances are:

- believed to be incompatible with each other by the TS compiler (because of the private property)
- believed to be (inherit from) `String` by the TS compiler, allowing string functions to be called
- actually real strings at runtime, providing runtime support for the supposedly inherited string functions

This is analogous to a "faked inheritance" (as the TS compiler is told about an inheritance, but that inheritance does not exist at runtime) with additional data validation. Since no public members or methods were added, this should never cause unexpected runtime behavior, as the same supposed functionality exists both during compilation and runtime.

Comment: Haha honestly I don't think it's as hacky as you say - a class that doesn't actually create a new object is definitely going to raise some eyebrows though. One advantage is that it gives a location for doing runtime validation that the string is actually in the expected format. But a disadvantage is that I would call those "constructor" helpers in a lot of places, e.g. everywhere I interface with Node's 'path' module. But with any solution I'll end up casting or something in that case.

Comment: @RobLourens Yes, although I believe the added verbosity is a reasonable price to pay, and will certainly have its advantages later on.

Comment: +1 For effort and for maybe being the only type of working solution, but I'm still curious if someone can define true structurally compatible types where the compiler still would not be able to confirm their compatibility. Although that do sounds like a bug in the first place...

Comment: +1 One thing that intrigues me. How much is the generated javascript different from the original javascript that just uses string? I love type checks, and the ability to catch errors in compile time rather than run time, but also like to know the drawbacks for the potential overhead.

Comment: @Fede `url` just passes through the creator functions. If there is no checking inside, the only overhead is the function invocation itself.

Comment: @Alex - for what it's worth I have highlighted two approaches to this problem in my answer - and the one involving type tagging with enums allows treating otherwise structurally compatible types as distinct.

Answer (score 25):

There are several ways to do this.  All of them involve "tagging" the target type using intersections.

### Enum tagging

We can leverage the fact that there is one nominal type in TypeScript - [the `Enum` type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#9) to distinguish otherwise structurally identical types:

> An enum type is a *distinct subtype* of the Number primitive type

#### What does this mean?

**Interfaces and classes are compared structurally**

```
interface First {}
interface Second {}

var x: First;
var y: Second;
x = y; // Compiles because First and Second are structurally equivalent
```

**Enums are distinct based on their "identity" (e. g. they are nominatively typed)**

```
const enum First {}
const enum Second {}

var x: First;
var y: Second;
x = y;  // Compilation error: Type 'Second' is not assignable to type 'First'.
```

We can take advantage of `Enum`'s nominal typing to "tag" or "brand" our *structural* types in one of two ways:

#### Tagging types with enum types

Since Typescript supports intersection types and type aliases we can "tag" any type with an enum and mark that as a new type.  We can then cast any instance of the base type to the "tagged" type without issue:

```
const enum MyTag {}
type SpecialString = string & MyTag;
var x = 'I am special' as SpecialString;
// The type of x is `string & MyTag`
```

We can use this behavior to "tag" strings as being `Relative` or `Absolute` paths (this wouldn't work if we wanted to tag a `number` - see the second option for how to handle those cases):

```
declare module Path {
  export const enum Relative {}
  export const enum Absolute {}
}

type RelativePath = string & Path.Relative;
type AbsolutePath = string & Path.Absolute;
type Path = RelativePath | AbsolutePath
```

We can then "tag" any instance of a string as any kind of `Path` simply by casting it:

```
var path = 'thing/here' as Path;
var absolutePath = '/really/rooted' as AbsolutePath;
```

However, there's no check in place when we cast so it's possible to:

```
var assertedAbsolute = 'really/relative' as AbsolutePath;
// compiles without issue, fails at runtime somewhere else
```

To mitigate this issue we can use control-flow based type checks to ensure that we only cast if a test passes (at run time):

```
function isRelative(path: String): path is RelativePath {
  return path.substr(0, 1) !== '/';
}

function isAbsolute(path: String): path is AbsolutePath {
  return !isRelative(path);
}
```

And then use them to ensure that we're handling the correct types *without any run-time errors*:

```
var path = 'thing/here' as Path;
if (isRelative(path)) {
  // path's type is now string & Relative
  withRelativePath(path);
} else {
  // path's type is now string & Absolute
  withAbsolutePath(path);
}
```

#### Generic structural "branding" of interfaces / classes

Unfortunately we cannot tag `number` subtypes like `Weight` or `Velocity` because Typescript is smart enough to reduce `number & SomeEnum` to just `number`. We **can** use generics and a field to "brand" a class or interface and get similar nominal-type behavior.  This is similar to what @JohnWhite suggests with his private name, but without the possibility of name collisions as long as the generic is an `enum`:

```
/**
 * Nominal typing for any TypeScript interface or class.
 *
 * If T is an enum type, any type which includes this interface
 * will only match other types that are tagged with the same
 * enum type.
 */
interface Nominal<T> { 'nominal structural brand': T }

// Alternatively, you can use an abstract class
// If you make the type argument `T extends string`
// instead of `T /* must be enum */`
// then you can avoid the need for enums, at the cost of
// collisions if you choose the same string as someone else
abstract class As<T extends string> {
  private _nominativeBrand: T;
}

declare module Path {
  export const enum Relative {}
  export const enum Absolute {}
}
type BasePath<T> = Nominal<T> & string
type RelativePath = BasePath<Path.Relative>
type AbsolutePath = BasePath<Path.Absolute>
type Path = RelativePath | AbsolutePath

// Mark that this string is a Path of some kind
// (The alternative is to use
// var path = 'thing/here' as Path
// which is all this function does).
function toPath(path: string): Path {
  return path as Path;
}
```

We have to use our "constructor" to create instances of our "branded" types from the base types:

```
var path = toPath('thing/here');
// or a type cast will also do the trick
var path = 'thing/here' as Path
```

And again, we can use control-flow based types and functions for additional compile-time safety:

```
if (isRelative(path)) {
  withRelativePath(path);
} else {
  withAbsolutePath(path);
}
```

And, as an added bonus, this also works for `number` subtypes:

```
declare module Dates {
  export const enum Year {}
  export const enum Month {}
  export const enum Day {}
}

type DatePart<T> = Nominal<T> & number
type Year = DatePart<Dates.Year>
type Month = DatePart<Dates.Month>
type Day = DatePart<Dates.Day>

var ageInYears = 30 as Year;
var ageInDays: Day;
ageInDays = ageInYears;
// Compilation error:
// Type 'Nominal<Month> & number' is not assignable to type 'Nominal<Year> & number'.
```

Adapted from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/185#issuecomment-125988288

Comment: That's a good idea, but I could also just replace the enum and brand with any arbitrary property that doesn't exist on the other interfaces, right?

Comment: I guess the value in doing in this way is that it's scalable, since I wouldn't be coming up with unique property names or something. And when the brand name is always the same, people will know what it means when they see it. (to be clear, I'm contrasting this with `interface Relative extends String { _fakeProperty1: any; }`. I like this better than that.)

Comment: @RobLourens - updated with more explanation as well as an alternative approach that uses intersection types.

Comment: @RobLourens I like what you are doing, but then casting throws an error for me.

Comment: Not sure in which TS version this was working, but at least with latest (3.9.2) it's *not* working:

    const enum MyTag {}
    const enum MyOtherTag {}

    type SpecialString = string & MyTag;
    type OtherSpecialString = string & MyOtherTag;

    const x: SpecialString = 'I am special' as SpecialString;

    const y: OtherSpecialString = x; // no error


Types for both are "never"

Comment: As far as I know this was still working in 3.8.x - the `Nominal<T>` interface version still works, even if the less-boilerplate `T & SomeEnum` no longer does.