# Explicit string alias type

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to make this code below fail.

When I create these `In` and `Out` types I'd love to have any strings passed into `usage` to have to be cast as `In`. Is this possible?

```
type In = string;
type Out = string;

const usage = (x: In): Out => 'meow';

usage('hi');
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260143/how-do-you-emulate-nominal-typing-in-typescript  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053800/typescript-specific-string-types

Answer (score 0):

I think for this we may have to create our own type instead of using the string type.
The type keyword in ts is just an alias for the types used, more details here -

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.10

So the above code is same as :

```
const usage = (x: string): string=> 'meow';
```

In case you are looking for some method that takes some object having a string property;

```
type In = {text:string};
type Out = string;

const usage = (x: In): Out => 'meow';
const data: In = { text: 'value' };
usage(data);
```