# Typescript - How to disallow two type aliases that resolve to the same type to be used interchangeably?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, typescript-typings

Let's say I have two or more type aliases, as such:

```
declare type A = string;
declare type B = string;
```

I have variables of these types, as well as functions that operate on them.

```
const a1: A = "example of a";
const b1: B = "example of b";

function withA(a: A){
    console.log(a);
}

function withB(b: B){
    console.log(b);
}
```

I would like the following code to error, but it does not:

```
withA(b1);
withB(a1);
```

How can I accomplish this? I will also need to be able to initialize the variables with a string (I'm assuming with a cast). However, once initialized I do not want the types to be "implicitly equivalent" and want to have the compiler forbid their interchangeable use.

I also would like to not have to use classes, as described here:
[TypeScript - specific string types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053800/typescript-specific-string-types)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type aliases as their name suggests don't add anything to the type they alias. So as far as TS is concerned both `A` and `B` are the same  type namely `string`.

What you can do is use branded types. This is a technique where you take the base type (`string` in this case) and intersect it with an object type with a property so as to make the type structurally incompatible with anything else from the compiler's point of view with. The property does not need to exist at runtime, it is just there as a marker for the compiler:

```
type A = string & { __brand: "A"};
type B = string & { __brand: "B"};

const a1: A = makeA("example of a");
const b1: B =  makeB("example of b");

function makeA(s: string) {
    return s as A
}
function makeB(s: string) {
    return s as B
}
function withA(a: A){
    console.log(a);
}

function withB(b: B){
    console.log(b);
}

withA(b1); // error
withB(a1); // error
```

The utility functions `makeA` and `makeB` are not strictly necessary, you can just use a type assertion when you assign the `string`, but they make the DX better.

**Note**: There are two proposals for formalizing this technique in the type system ([Structural `tag type` brands](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33290) and [Nominal `unique type` brands](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33038) ) but neither is merged at the time of writing, maybe in a future TS version we will get one of these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to use the branded type you have described as an index parameter type into an object, but I am greeted with: `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)`. Do you know how I can get around this? My property looks like this: `foos: Readonly<{ [key: A]: Foo }>;`

Comment: @vasia not possible, TS requires the index to be either string or number, even `string | number` is forbidden.

Comment: Are there any extensions to typescript one can use to get this functionality - as it's not officially merged yet

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi no, but the syntax would just be sugar on top of the branded types pattern.